# Are Uranus, Neptune and Pluto mentioned in any scripture?

Tags: mahabharata, identification-request, science

According to [this](https://www.booksfact.com/science/ancient-science/uranus-neptune-pluto-mentioned-in-mahabharata.html) website, the planets Uranus, Neptune and Pluto were mentioned in the Mahabharata. The site cites the following verses:

> Vishesheena hi Vaarshneya Chitraam Pidayate Grahah….[10-Udyog.143]
>
> Swetograhastatha Chitraam Samitikryamya Tishthati….[12-Bheeshma.3]

The above verses is said to be talking about the planet Uranus.

The following verses are said to be talking about the planet Neptune:

> Shukrahah Prosthapade Poorve Samaruhya Virochate Uttare tu Parikramya Sahitah Samudikshyate….[15-Bheeshma.3]
>
> Syamograhah Prajwalitah Sadhooma iva Pavakah Aaindram Tejaswi Naksha- tram Jyesthaam Aakramya Tishthati…[16-Bheeshma.3]

And these verses are said to be talking about the planet Pluto:

> Krittikaam Peedayan Teekshnaihi Nakshatram…[30-Bheeshma.3]
>
> Krittikasu Grahasteevro Nakshatre Prathame Jvalan…… [26- Bhishma.3]

Are these claims authentic and hold any scriptural basis? Do any scripture "apart from the Mahabharata" talk about the planets Uranus, Neptune and Pluto?

Comment: Highly unlikely. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discovery_of_Neptune): "Neptune is too dim to be visible to the naked eye: its apparent magnitude is never brighter than 7.7. Therefore, the first observations of Neptune were only possible after the invention of the telescope."

Comment: the modern definition of planet is not same as 'graha'. Earth is not a graha but it's a planet. Sun is a graha but it's not a planet.

Comment: Without sounding pompous - the knowledge of the ancients in Bhatavarsha was quite advanced.  They may have had powerful instruments similar to telescopes and may have had knowledge of Neptune, Uranus and Pluto. Modern scientific knowledge is still too shallow and one of the axioms is "We know more than our ancient ancestors." Modern science rubbishes UFO stories. One abductee Betty Hill from New Hampshire narrated that a needle was inserted into her navel - a pregnancy test - by the aliens and was promptly dubbed a hoax because no such test exited in 1961. Isn't that what laproscopy tests do?

Answer (score 2):

Except the 5th verse you provided all other verses are present in BORI EDITION

Your 1st verse - see 141 section 9th shloka
https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/txt/mbh05.itx

translation is - see 35-36 https://archive.org/details/the-mahabharata-set-of-10-volumes-by-bibek-debroy-veda-vyasa-vyasa-veda-vyas-z-lib.org/page/n2665/mode/2up in the notes Bibek writes

35.Anuradha is the seventeenth nakshatra and Jyeshtha is the eighteenth. Because Mars is retrograde, it is moving from the eighteenth to the seventeenth. The lord of Anuradha is Mitra, signifying friendship. Mitra means a friend and is also the name of a god.
36. Chitra (Spica) is the fourteenth nakshatra. The planet in question must be Mars, because Mars is the lord of Chitra."

Your 2nd verse - see 3rd section 11th shloka ,3rd verse - see 3rd section 14th shloka , 4th verse - see 3rd section 15th shloka , 6th verse - see 3rd section 26th shloka https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/txt/mbh06.itx

Translation is https://archive.org/details/the-mahabharata-set-of-10-volumes-by-bibek-debroy-veda-vyasa-vyasa-veda-vyas-z-lib.org/page/n2939/mode/2up

this is what bibek wrote in notes https://archive.org/details/the-mahabharata-set-of-10-volumes-by-bibek-debroy-veda-vyasa-vyasa-veda-vyas-z-lib.org/page/n3505/mode/2up so even Bibek is not sure .

Now coming to gita press translation.

https://archive.org/download/unabridged-mahabharata-6-volumes-set-in-hindi-by-veda-vyasa-compressed  click on volume 3 which has both udyog and bhishma parva.

For your 1st verse , translation is [image: 1st verse]
For your 2nd,3rd and 4th verse, translation is [image: 2nd 3rd 4th]
Your 6th verse is not in gita press translation , while for your 5th verse , translation is[image: 5th verse]

So from gita press translation there is as such no mention of uranus,neptune and pluto .  "mahapat upgraha" is unknown but its clear these 3 planets are not mentioned,

Comment: Please explain the gist of your answer or add TLDR

Comment: @GabeHiemstra TLDR means ? well i wrote conclusion , i suppose thats fine ?

Comment: Basically it means, please add summary on top explaining the answer in one or two sentences. But I suppose your conclusion is fine, thanks :)

Comment: @GabeHiemstra oh ok thanks :-) , please do upvote if my answer is satisfying , if it is not satisfying then I will improve it :-) By the way I must say I am very much amazed by hardwork you have done by creating wisdom lib website , everyone uses that website for sources , we all are quite grateful to you :-)

Comment: Thanks, and welcome :)